# ASP .net Core hosted in Azure missing insight data

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, kestrel

We have a ASP .NET Core web api hosted in Azure. Requests and Telemetry data is logged just fine but there is no performance counters tracked for memory and CPU.

I think it is because the application is not running on IIS but I am a bit uncertain how it all works here, could someone help me with some information I would be greatful!

Comment: Performance Counter [is enabled by default](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Dependency-Tracking-and-Performance-Counter-Collection). Did you configure the AI in your application or only active in azure portal?

Comment: I only added it in the portal and configured the key in the config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance telemetry is currently not supported in .NET Core. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Dependency-Tracking-and-Performance-Counter-Collection).